# Driver install failure "deleted" motherboard ethernet adapter

Tags: drivers, internet, ethernet, intel, lspci

System: Ubuntu 22

Motherboard: supermicro h11dsi

Issue:
After first installation of ubuntu, I cannot connect to internet via wired network. `lspci | grep -i net` shows two `intel i350 ethernet controller`. Some people advised to install the driver for this adapater. So I downloaded the latest driver from Intel and tried to install it following the instruction. (https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/14098/intel-network-adapter-driver-for-82575-6-82580-i350-and-i210-211-based-gigabit-network-connections-for-linux.html)

(I remembered I installed `gcc, build-essential, linux-head($uname-r)`. Then `update`. Then decompressed the igb-5.7.2 package, `cd ./src`, and `sudo make install`. )

At `make install` step, it report some error message.But the module `igb` can be installed in my machine. `modprobe igb` did not print any error message.

After that,  `lspci | grep -i net` prints empty information. I tried to check the full list of lspci. None ethernet device were found.

I don't know how to uninstall it or reverse the setting. So I reinstall the system again. But it didn't work.

I checked lspci in USB boot system, it is the same.

At last, I entered the BIOS. In `Advance setting`, I can see IPMI Lan and LAN1 are enabled. But when entering `network configuration`, it is totally empty.

I also checked jumper JPL1 on the motherboard. It is 1-2 linked (which means LAN1 and LAN2 are enabled on board).

I feel hopeless that I can't recover the ethernet device, but it is strange because I could connect to internet via USB (with my iPhone sending a hotspot signal)

How could a driver installation failure "delete" the ethernet adapater "physically" on ubuntu???
Does anyone meet this situation before?
And, if I failed to install a driver, how can I prevent this from happening again? How to uninstall it cleanly? Or make sure `make install` works.

I have to buy a new ethernet controller, but I'm afraid this would happen again. Could you please help me?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Ubuntu 22 - so you're asking about Ubuntu Core 22?   (the *year* format releases differ to the more widely used *year.month* releases; ie. 22 is not 22.04; but a *flavor* of 22 with different limitations & benefits)

Comment: I very strongly doubt that installing a driver could delete the hardware. You can remove it with: `sudo make uninstall` On my Ubuntu 22.04 system, the driver *igb* is already present and need not be installed seperately. After you run the uninstall, please run: `lspci` and edit your question to show the result. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 I've tried to work around with this issue yesterday. I have some strange findings. It indeed "delete" the firmware at first because the BIOS doesn't even find any network controller. I don't understand how it could have done this. I tried to identified ethernet controller by reinstalling ubuntu 22.04. After I cut off the power and reboot system, I could detect ethernet controller again BUT still cannot connect to internet. At last, I changed system to Ubuntu 20.04.4. It did not have connection until I cut off the power for a few minutes/hours. It connected eventually.

Comment: @guiverc @chili555 I think the issue may be nothing to do with Ubuntu system. Failure of driver installation should not affect firmware, but it indeed returns empty result from command `lspci | grep -i net` in Ubuntu 22.04/20.04.4 system, Ubuntu PE system and even after reinstallation. I guess it may be a protective strategy, compatibility issue or something else about the server motherboard but not the system. I might ask a wrong question in wrong place. But still so many thanks to you.